# Display Previous Months in Shell

Tags: macos, shell

I have extracted the current month using

```
currentMonth=`date +"%b"`
```

I want to get all previous five months in a file. Suppose its October now, i want Sep, Aug, Jul, Jun, May in a file. I tried using multiple utilities like cal, ncal, date but could not achieve this. 
I want the months in the file as 
Sep
Aug
Jul
Jun
May
Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple **`bash/shell`** solution (for *Unix*):

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do date -d" - $i month" +%b; done
```

The output:

```
Sep
Aug
Jul
Jun
May
```

---

For *MacOS*:

```
for i in {1..5}; do date -v-"$i"m +%b; done
```

Comment: Its giving me error  -- usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]

Comment: @Prashast, are you on Linux?

Comment: I am using Mac terminal

Comment: @Prashast, let me give you an advise: always add a tag `macos`, `osx` to your questions to avoid confusing